# Odd effect of letter-spacing on element width

Tags: css

I would have assumed that setting letter-spacing to -1px on a two-character span would reduce its width by 1px. However, see the following in Chrome:

```
span.style.fontSize=48
48
span.textContent="99"
"99"
span.style.letterSpacing=0
0
span.offsetWidth
16
span.style.letterSpacing="-1px"
"-1px"
span.offsetWidth
14
```

Setting letter-spacing to -1px has reduced the width by 2px rather than 1.

This might be less important if it did not cause the text with letter-spacing of -1px to be slight off-center when you are trying to align it with text-align: center.

The CSS spec appears to say clearly that letter-spacing is supposed to affect spacing *between* letters. However, it seems that at least in Chrome the spacing between some conceptual start point and the first character of text is also compressed.

Any ideas or thoughts on this? IE 10 exhibits the same behavior. A bug? Or misreading of the spec?

Comment: If you have three letters, won't the width decrease by `-2px` (`-1px` for each letter, not counting one of the endpoints)?

Comment: In Chrome, with a string of three letters, the width decreases by 3px rather than the expected (?) 2px.

Comment: That might be a bug in Chrome then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Behavior

I agree that the spec states this fairly explicitly. To quote [this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#letter-spacing):

> Letter-spacing must not be applied at the beginning or at the end of a
>   line.

However, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rm5SC/17/) on Win 7 is showing me that on Chrome, IE9, and Firefox, *all* are applying one less pixel after the last letter (Firefox is showing me to start out with one less pixel to begin with in the gap to the border), which seems to be in violation of it not being applied to the end of the line. The result being that all appear to be reducing total width by 1px per character in the string.

So it does not appear that it works as is should in any browser, nor does it matter if the `letter-spacing` is [instead a positive number](http://jsfiddle.net/Rm5SC/22/).

### Probably the "Best" Workaround

Add `padding-right: 1px` to the `span` with `letter-spacing: -1px` to offset the problem [as seen in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rm5SC/21/).

### Optional Workaround: `:after` pseudo-element

On the `span` with `letter-spacing: -1px` put the following [as seen in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rm5SC/20/):

```
span:after {content:''; display: inline-block; width: 1px;}
```

### Final Thought

Either solution above *may or may not* help with differences in `text-align: center` calculations, as that appears to partially depend on the 1px rounding for center based on the display width, as seen when one stretches the width of [this fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Rm5SC/25/).

Comment: Thanks for this most informative answer. The padding solution doesn't seem to work for me, but what did was `margin-left: -0.5px`. Still, it seems like a bug in the browser and it's curious that the same bug would exist in both Chrome and IE.

Comment: As a note on a year old answer: This also happens in mobile browsers, at least Chrome on Android. My issue involved overflow: hidden clipping the last bit of letters, and the "best" workaround fixed it.